# mod_rewrite / breaks JS and CSS files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problem with Mod Rewrite Rules and I think we may help me.
My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ http://www.dejwid.pl/demo/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

in index.php I divide $_GET['p'] using '/':

```
$params = explode('/', $_GET['']);
```

My problem:
if I using '/' images, js files, css files don't work.
I think the server can't find it because I'm using '/'.
If I use ',' or '-' etc. everything works great.
However I need address like this: domain/blog/123/Some-Title

Answer (score 2):

Your rule that matches ^(.+)$ is probably matching on your css and js files.

It is common to put these two conditions in front of a rule, to prevent the rule from matching when the URL is a real file, such as a css or js file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: @Dejwid, I'm sorry but I'm not sure what part is not working. When a css file is retrieved, is your index.php file called instead? Or is your problem with the $params values?